# Click on menu-item that is sometimes in the overflow-menu

Tags: android, android-espresso, optionmenu

currently to click on menu-item that is sometimes on some devices in the overflow-menu I am doing the following:

```
fun invokeMenu(@IdRes menuId: Int, @StringRes menuStringRes: Int) {
 try {
  onView(withId(menuId)).perform(click())
 } catch (nmv: NoMatchingViewException) {
  openActionBarOverflowOrOptionsMenu(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext)
  onView(withText(menuStringRes)).perform(click())
 }
}
```

But I am searching for a better approach - ideally something where I just have to know the menu-id. How do you do this in your espresso tests?

Answer (score 9):

Unfortunately, your ideal case cannot be acomplished. This is due to the construction of support libraries.

Let's start from [`PopupMenu`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/widget/PopupMenu.java#48), which has a reference to [`MenuPopupHelper`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuPopupHelper.java#58), which has reference to [`MenuPopup`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuPopup.java). This is an abstract class extended ie. by [`StandardMenuPopup`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/view/menu/StandardMenuPopup.java). It has reference to [`MenuAdapter`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuAdapter.java#92). If you look into the line 92 of `MenuAdapter` you will see, the line:

```
itemView.initialize(getItem(position), 0);
```

This is the key method invocation. It can be invoked either in [`ActionMenuItemView`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/view/menu/ActionMenuItemView.java) or [`ListMenuItemView`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/view/menu/ListMenuItemView.java). Their implementations  differ in the case, that [id is attached to ActionMenuItemView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/view/menu/ActionMenuItemView.java#132), and [is not attached to ListMenuItemView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/view/menu/ListMenuItemView.java#102)

Moreover, [`MenuAdapter.getItemId(int position)`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/src/android/support/v7/view/menu/MenuAdapter.java#80) returns just `position`. The id of menu item is lost in overflow menu.

---

Hovewer, your code can be simplified to one liner. Define a function:

```
public static Matcher<View> withMenuIdOrText(@IdRes int id, @StringRes int menuText) {
    Matcher<View> matcher = withId(id);
    try {
        onView(matcher).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
        return matcher;
    } catch (Exception NoMatchingViewException) {
        openActionBarOverflowOrOptionsMenu(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext());
        return withText(menuText);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
onView(withMenuIdOrText(R.id.menu_id, R.string.menu_text)).perform(click());
```